# Both Axios and Fetch return different/modified data than the network response

Tags: json, axios, fetch

I have figured out what the issue was. I'll keep this up here for the sake of others, and possibly future me.

I was inadvertently manipulating the object directly, in my case by
executing a `pop()` method on the character list, which of course updated the object in the console.

I fixed this by doing `[...items].pop()` instead, and so not to directly manipulate the object.

=======================================

When I make a GET request, the network tab shows the correct data, but the Axios or Fetch response returns slightly different data.

**Network tab - GET response**
Note the three characters.
[Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVxpD.png)

**Console Log - output of response**
Note that there are only two characters.
[Axios or Fetch result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAVbb.png)

**Axios Code**

```
const result = await axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_PATH}/${endpoint}/${id}`,
  headers,
  params: { cacheBuster: new Date().getTime() },
});

console.group(`loadOne - Axios`);
console.log('result:', result);
console.groupEnd();

return result.data;
```

I did find that by adding an extra item to the array on the server side, I got all of the characters (less the extra one).

It seems to truncate the array by one item when it is parsing the JSON.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution or fix for this strange behavior?

I tried using `fetch` as an alternative to Axios.  I got the same strange result.

I did find that by adding an extra item to the array I got all of the characters.

It seems to truncate the array by one item when it is parsing the JSON.

Adding an extra item to the list on the server seems to solve the issue, but that seems more of a kluge.